# Can I use a 3D gimbal system as a simplistic quadcopter IMU(3 axis accelerometer)?

Tags: quadcopter, accelerometer, gyroscope

i have 3d gimbal system and i want to use this sensor in place of IMU(3 axsis accelerometer) in Quadcopter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A gimbal system will not replace an accelerometer. I assume by gimbal system you mean something like a [Gyroscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope), i.e. a device that has a fixed orientation allowing you to measure your orientation relative to it.

A gyroscope can give you information on orientation and possibly angular velocity. An accelerometer gives you information on acceleration/gravity. Since the accelerometer can identify the direction of gravity using a couple simple assumptions, you can also use it to estimate your orientation.

Final answer: a gimbal/gyroscope can replace an accelerometer for the purposes of calculating the orientation of a device/quadcopter, a gimbal cannot replace the full functionality of an accelerometer.